# What are the differences between All Pages, Consent Initialization-All Pages and Initialization-All pages in Google Tag Manager Trigger types?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have always used `All Pages` for triggering the Configuration Tag(which is called Google Tag, recently) in **Google Tag Manager**, but now I am getting dubious.

What are the differences between various types of a Trigger (**All Pages**, **Consent Initialization-All Pages** and **Initialization-All pages**) listed in photo below?

[image]

Do they change the behaviour of Google Analytics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Consent Initialization:** Designed to help ensure that consent settings are honored before any other triggers fire. The Consent Initialization trigger is used for tags that set or update the user consent state for your site, such as a Consent Management Platform tag or tags that set consent defaults. Each web container includes a Consent Initialization - All Pages trigger by default. The Consent Initialization trigger is not used for tags that should fire early on a site. For those cases, use an Initialization trigger.

**Initialization**: Designed to fire before all other triggers except Consent Initialization triggers. Each web container includes an Initialization - All Pages trigger by default. Select this trigger to fire any tags that should fire before other triggers.

**[source](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679319?hl=en)**